# How to fix UINavigationBar title using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am new for ios in my project i need to add UINavigationBar title using Auto-layouts and for this i have written all my UInavigation bar title Properties in background class using autolayouts but when i run program showing exceptions please help me

### my main class:-

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){

    Back * bg;
    UINavigationController * bar;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    bg = [[Back alloc]init];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = [bg NavigationBar:bar];
}
```

### my backGroundClass:-

```
   #import "Back.h"

@implementation Back

UILabel * middle;
UILabel * left;
UILabel * right;
NSDictionary * viewsDic;
UINavigationController * MainnavigationBar;

-(UILabel*)NavigationBar :(UINavigationController*)navigationBar{

    MainnavigationBar = navigationBar;

    middle = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    middle.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    middle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [MainnavigationBar.navigationBar addSubview:middle];

    viewsDic = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(middle);

    [MainnavigationBar.navigationBar addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:middle
                                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                   toItem:MainnavigationBar.navigationBar
                                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                               multiplier:1
                                                                                 constant:0]];

    [MainnavigationBar.navigationBar addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:middle
                                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                   toItem:MainnavigationBar.navigationBar
                                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                               multiplier:1
                                                                                 constant:0]];

    [MainnavigationBar.navigationBar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:[middle(2)]"]
                                                                                            options:0
                                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                                              views:viewsDic]];

    [MainnavigationBar.navigationBar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[middle(30)]"]
                                                                                            options:0
                                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                                              views:viewsDic]];


    return middle;
}

@end
```

Comment: i am very beginner in ios that's why i have written like that if you know solution please help me

Comment: when i call my background class method it's showing exceptions

Comment: Hey Don't take BackGround class as one of viewControllers it must be UIView in your case. @HiteshBoricha is right....

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can set Title view using below line in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear method

`[self.navigationItem setTitleView:YourView];`

Here you can take YourView as UILabel, UIImageView, UIButton and so on....

Don't add label as a SubView of UINavigationBar

**Sorry My Mistake Please Take Your BackGroundClass as a UIView
Don't take BackGroundClass as a UIViewController or any Controller it must be a Simple UIView in your case...** I saw that background class has viewDidLoad its surprising...

Comment: so your saying need to take background class as UIview instaed of UIViewController

Comment: see i have edited my code still exceptions are coming